# Why does Arkadź Kulašoǔ live on Moscow Street, and where is this?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, arkadz-kulasou

Arkadź Kulašoǔ has a poem entitled "Moscow Street," which starts with the line "I live on Moscow Street, I have my home there".

Where is Moscow Street? Is this actually in Moscow? If so, why is this in a collection of Belarusian poetry?

Is there some significance to this street, or is the poet just being sentimental for home?

Comment: it took me some time to find that you mean Arkadi Kuleshov (Аркадзь Куляшоў)

Comment: @Andra That's a little different than how it was transposed in my book. (I obviously can't transpose the book exactly using an English keyboard, though).

Comment: @EJoshuaS: It's a difference between transliterations from Belarusian (Arkadź Kulašoǔ) and via Russian (Arkadi Kuleshov). I updated the post to use the Belarusian transliteration, which is the one in *Like Water, Like Fire*. Also I removed "Biesiadz" which somehow got in by mistake from the title of the preceding poem, "My Biesiadz".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article in Russian by vadim_i_z:
[A little-known high street in the center of Minsk. Moscow Street: transport, houses and people](https://vadim-i-z.livejournal.com/4225755.html)

where the author writes about this street in Minsk. He also mentions poet Arkadi Kuleshov (Аркадий Кулешов) and cites a verse from the poem. Kuleshov once lived in house "№ 16" (search this in Vadim's text) in apartment 61.
The poet's name in Belorussian is Аркадзь Куляшоў.